# HTML code changes and messes up when previewing from webhost in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, tags, markup

I created a HTML page. When I preview it locally, it works fine. I then upload it to my server, and preview it through my browsers. IE works fine, however Firefox wont show my `<input type="image"...`tag. I then looked through the code in Firefox using Firebug, and this is what the tag looked like:

```
<input id="submitbtn" class=" teyinwkwhnsodpgjocmv" type="image" src="Images/aff-login.png">
```

And this is what **my** code looks like:

```
<input type="image" id="submitbtn" src="Images/aff-login.png" />
```

See, no classname! But why does Firefox add that? And why only when previewing it from my server?

Comment: What add-ons are your running?

Comment: I'd be inclined to use view source / the net panel in firebug / fiddler to see if it's a transmission issue or a browser issue. Firebug renders to dom back to code in HTML view so is not suited to troubleshooting here. I assume you've cleared all caches?

Comment: @PeeHaa @spender - it appears it was AdBlock Plus that removed it. Why would it do that? How can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: I got it - it was the filename that was the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was AdBlock Plus. After inspecting my filters, I found that it would block stuff that started with `aff-`.

The solution is to use another filename. :)